# How to use custom setting's value to display record in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to display records of an object in lightning component. Since the number of fields to be displayed is very high, I want to store fields in custom setting and iterate over it instead writing each fields on code. So my sample code is something like this.

```
<aura:iteration items="mycustomsetting" var="fieldname">
          {!v.account[fieldname]}
 </aura:iteration>
```

But this syntax is not supported. Want to know will this be possible via the correct syntax or some other way around

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but it is easier if you just use `lightning:recordForm` from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation
You can pass list of fields, comma separated to it, and set the mode to view this way you achieve it without iteration.